# Python: Open 2 CMD/TERMONALS; one for INPUT and another for OUTPUT

Tags: python, cmd

What I'm trying to achieve is to open 2 CMDs (Windows) or Terminals (OS X/Mac). One for receiving input (via raw_input) and another for output (via print), I know this might be possible using Pythons process thingy, but I don't know how to go about this. If you don't understand I will repeat it:

-One CMD/Terminal where uses can type input
-Another CMD/Terminal where the user can see the output

I will need it in 1 file, not 2 different files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no simple way to do that. The *natural* way to have one window for input and one for output would be the `tkinter`, but that will not look like a CMD window in Windows.

As soon as you want to open a new *terminal* window, it will not be hidden behind one of the OS independant Python modules, and you will have to explicitely open two consoles and use their low level IO commands through ctypes under Windows, and open two terminals under OS X.

IMHO, unless you have a very strong need for it, you do not want such a complex thing.